# Recorder in which I can record while pausing is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a student and when I read any book then whatever I understand by reading any section of that book, I record it(*in a sound recorder*).

My brother advised me that I must write whatever I understand but with me it happens that when I start writing then I skip some small(but useful) informations to write because it becomes lengthy.

What problem I face while recording in a recorder is as follows:

Suppose I am reading a particular section of a book which have four paragraphs. After reading a paragraph I understand the meaning(in detail) of that paragraph and I have some problems regarding that paragraph. So I decided to record it. Till now I have not started the second paragraph. Now at this point I have to pause the recorder and then read the paragraph understand the meaning and then continue the recording.**The problem is that in Ubuntu 12.04 I use 'sound recorder', this sound recorder have only start and stop button. This means that I can not pause the recorder.**

Kindly help me in finding a recorder which suits my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Audacity** for the your needs.

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: sir this worked for me but now there is a problem, it always save the audio with .aup extension and therefore it do not work with vlc. Is there any way by which I can save the audio with a extension so that it works with vlc too.

Comment: I thought vlc can play almost any type of file... Are u sure it can't play .aup files ?

Comment: Sir I'm sure it is not working with vlc.